# finding locations within a particular distance using db2

Tags: geolocation, db2

I am using html5 geolocation api to get my position in latitude and longitude. I want to store them in a table  of locations and want to retrieve those locations within a particular distance.

my current latitudes and longitudes are stored in variables "latval", "longval", "distance"
My table is "location"
columns are "location", "lat", "long" 
I am using DB2 Express C as database and latitude and longitude columns are set as double type now. What type should I use to store these values and what would be the query to get location names within a distance
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an extension for Express C that includes Spatial processing.  I've never used it (and can't seem to get access at the moment), so I can't speak to it.  I'm assuming that you'd want to use that (find all locations within a radius is a pretty standard query).

If for some reason you can't use the extension, here's what I would do:
Keep your table as-is, or maybe use a float data-type, although please use full attribute names (there's no reason to truncate them).  For simple needs, the name of the 'location' can be stored in the table, but you may want to give it a numeric id if more than one thing is at the same location (so actual points are only in there once).
You're also going to want indicies covering latitude and longitude (probably one each way, or one covering each column).

Then, given a starting position and distance, use this query:

```
SELECT name, latitude, longitude
FROM location
WHERE (latitude >= :currentLatitude - :distance
       AND latitude <= :currentLatitude + :distance)
AND (longitude >= :currentLongitude - :distance
     AND longitude <= :currentLongitude + :distance)
  -- The previous four lines reduce the points selected to a box.
  -- This is, or course, not completely correct, but should allow
  -- the query to use the indicies to greatly reduce the initial 
  -- set of points evaluated.
  -- You may wish to flip the condition and use ABS(), but
  -- I don't think that would use the index...
AND POWER(latitude - :currentLatitude, 2) + POWER(longitude - :currentLongitude, 2) 
         <= POWER (:distance, 2)
  -- This uses the pythagorean theorem to find all points within the specified
  -- distance.  This works best if the points have been pre-limited in some
  -- way, because an index would almost certainly not be used otherwise.
  -- Note that, on a spherical surface, this isn't completely accurate
  --  - namely, distances between longitude points get shorter the farther
  --       from the equator the latitude is - 
  -- but for your purposes is likely to be fine.
```

---

EDIT:

Found [this after searching for 2 seconds on google](http://weevilgenius.net/2010/04/calculating-distances-in-sql/), which also reminded me that `:distance` would be in the wrong units.  The revised query is:

```
WITH Nearby (name, latitude, longitude, dist) as (
 SELECT name, latitdude, longitude,
       ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(:currentLatitude)) + 
            COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(:currentLatitude)) * 
            COS(RADIANS(:currentLongitude - longitude))) * :RADIUS_OF_EARTH as dist
FROM location 
WHERE (latitude >= :currentLatitude - DEGREES(:distance / :RADIUS_OF_EARTH)
       AND latitude <= :currentLatitude + DEGREES(:distance / :RADIUS_OF_EARTH))
AND (longitude >= :currentLongitude - 
               DEGREES(:distance / :RADIUS_OF_EARTH / COS(RADIANS(:currentLatitude)))
     AND longitude <= :currentLongitude + 
               DEGREES(:distance / :RADIUS_OF_EARTH / COS(RADIANS(:currentLatitude))))
)
SELECT *
FROM Nearby
WHERE dist <= :distance
```

Please note that wrapping the distance function in a UDF marked `DETERMINISTIC` would allow it to be placed in both the `SELECT` and `HAVING` portions, but only actually be called *once*, eliminating the need for the CTE.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am looking for the query for distance using spherical formula. what is the query using the great circle distance formula?

Comment: Thank you so much x-zero. I am in my college now. I will check if it is working after I go home. I also installed spatial extender. But I am not able to figure out on storing the coordinates in it. let me know if u know anything about it which would be of great help.. you can find spatial extender at the plugins for db2 page.

Comment: I have tried the above query . its returning me the following error

SQL0206N  "DIST" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703

SQL0206N  "DIST '

Comment: the following query is working but no results are being shown when using the bounding coordinates formula. 

      `WITH Nearby as (SELECT NAME,ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) *
       SIN(RADIANS(17.386211)) + COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(17.386211)) * COS(RADIANS(78.430578 - longitude)))*6371 as dist FROM TEST ) SELECT * FROM Nearby WHERE dist <= 10`

Comment: Please note that there is some error in the formula, mostly because of imprecisions relating to the representation (that is, because floats/doubles can't precisely represent some numbers).  Are you sure you have points listed within that distance?